# Literature -search for reference -details such as Author, Title, Year, Type and Publisher? Ready exporting to Bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, texniccenter

TexNicCenter has a Literature -search but it does not work. Suppose I write a number-theoretic -paper and a reference is a book but I cannot remember its publication details such as Author, Year and Publisher. I currently use Bibtex and I always manually enter things but after seeing the Literature -search in TexNicCenter, I started to think there may be some sort of platform-independent reference -search.

> 1. Does there exist some sort of tool that could help me to find fast the details (not going to library or using google)?
> 2. Does it export things to Bibtex -format?
> 3. Some sort of tool exist in Apple -products that helps to search academic papers (pay-only) but I haven't yet seen any platform-independent tool that could help to fill the reference details to formats such as bibtex. Also it is monotonous working to keep track of refrencese, perhaps some tool also to store refrences. Just brainstorming, ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to cite mathematical references, there are several browser search tools available from the AMS that will deliver results in BibTeX form:

- [MR Lookup](http://www.ams.org/mrlookup)
- [MRef](http://www.ams.org/mref/)
- [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/)

The first two are accessible to anyone; MathSciNet requires the searcher to be covered under a license, available to those associated with many academic institutions (check with the library).

Varing amounts of identifying information must be provided to the search: if an author has published only a few items, then the author name may be sufficient; for more prolific authors, the search should be narrowed down by publication name, date, keywords from the title, and similar elements.  If an item has a DOI, a link will be included in the BibTeX reference.

Comment: Then there is the more general [CiteULike](http://www.citeulike.org/)